# What is the behavior of promises in React when a user leaves the webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, metamask

I am using Metamask to deploy a contract on Ethereum. The deploy contract function returns a promise that will resolve after the contract has been confirmed by the Ethereum network. This takes some time. After the promise resolves, I would like to send some information in my website's database. How can I save this information to the database even if the user leaves the webpage before the promise has resolved and the contract has been deployed?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the page, effectively, quits the JavaScript program running in it. Nothing will listen for the promises to be resolved.

To run JavaScript when the user isn't viewing the page, use a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).